# Is Citizen-Based Taxation Constitutional?

Tags: constitutional-law, tax-law

The U.S. is currently one of two countries in the world that imposes taxes on all her its citizens regardless of where they live or where they earn money from. The other is Eritrea.

Considering that one of the primary grievances which sparked the American Revolution was "taxation without representation", Citizen-Based Taxation is quite ironic. There are no elected representatives for American citizens abroad and their interests are almost never considered.

From a constitutional perspective, is it legal to force a U.S. citizen living abroad and earning a living abroad to pay taxes to the U.S. despite having no representation, and receiving no benefits in return - in addition to being deprived of the basic freedom to expatriate (the tax and filing requirements are so onerous for Americans abroad it is in most respects unfeasable to live abroad. Those that do are overwhelmingly not compliant).

What are the arguments for and against?

Comment: I don't think your factual claim is correct. See the table at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_taxation

Comment: @user6726 actually it is. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_taxation#Citizenship

Answer (score 7):

- I know of no specific provision of the Constitution that would forbid it.
- I know of no court case in which it has been found unconstitutional.
- There's no "irony" clause in the Constitution.  Taxation without representation may have been a grievance, but there's no inherent reason why  the framers would have had to forbid it.
- US citizens do still have the "freedom to expatriate" (and avoid taxation) if they renounce their citizenship.
- There are already other examples of "taxation without representation" in US law (e.g. District of Columbia), which also have not been found unconstitutional in court, as far as I know.
- In many cases, expatriates can still vote for federal offices, including Congress (e.g. in a state where they used to live, or where a parent used to live).  See https://www.fvap.gov/citizen-voter/registration-ballots.
- The Sixteenth Amendment gives Congress the power to "lay and collect taxes" with few limitations.  There is certainly no explicit exception for expatriates.  As far as I can tell, it would be constitutional if Congress were to impose an income tax on everybody in the world, regardless of residency or citizenship; it would just be hard to enforce.

Comment: Also, the fact that you earn income outside the United States, for example, you sell some real estate you own in France at a profit, does not imply that you do not reside in the United States and vote for representatives at your residence.

Comment: It is also worth noting that while once you expatriate you are not long subject to U.S. income taxes based solely upon citizenship and not any other effective connection of the income to the U.S., there is a tax which has been held to be constitutional which is imposed upon the act of expatriation if you have substantial assets (roughly comparable to the taxes that would be owed if you died on that date).

Answer (score 1):

A US citizen abroad CAN vote in elections. According to the state department,

> Most U.S. citizens 18 years or older who reside outside the United States are eligible to vote absentee for federal office candidates in U.S. primary and general elections.

There is no taxation without representation.

You may not be using US services abroad, but that's your choice. As a US citizen, you are free to return to the US and use its resources as you please. That freedom is why you pay taxes. As @NateEldredge said, you can always choose to expatriate if you do not want to pay taxes and have no intention of returning to the US. You can't have the best of both worlds.

Source: [Absentee Voting Information for U.S. Citizens Abroad](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/abroad/legal-matters/benefits/voting.html)

Comment: Just to be clear "taxation without representation" is a political slogan and not a rule of law. Lots of people who are not entitled to vote still owe taxes and that is not unconstitutional. People with no U.S. residence in a U.S. state, non-citizens, minors, some felons and people not registered to vote can't vote in federal elections either and they still are constitutionally and usually legally obligated to pay federal taxes. There are a few statutory exceptions (e.g. foreign wage income up to $X and certain Puerto Rico income).

Comment: @Byte11 living abroad is not "the best of both worlds". It's actually the worst of both worlds. Yes, expatriation is _technically_ but it is made so expensive and so cumbersome that a tiny number of people can actually manage to go through with it each year. Realistically it's not an option.

Comment: @CH Yes, that's what I meant when I said "You can't have the best of both worlds."

Answer (score -2):

I agree with Nate Eldredge that the constitution doesn't specifically prohibit citizenship-based taxation. It's certainly a moral argument that the people being taxed be eligible for the benefits funded by their taxes, and that they be somehow represented in the entity imposing the taxes, but the constitution doesn't require these conditions.

However, the 5th amendment prohibits taxation without due process, which requires a rational basis for personal classifications, according to well established judicial precedent. A tax based on an irrational classification, for example different tax rates depending on the number of vowels in the person's name, would be ruled unconstitutional. It's very rare to find a case where a court invalidated a tax due to this restriction, because tax classifications tend to be based on rational economic factors and courts tend to completely defer to the legislature in this area, but there are indeed a few cases where courts invalidated tax provisions that were based on personal characteristics. For example, see [Moritz v. Commissioner](https://law.justia.com/cases/federal/appellate-courts/F2/469/466/79852/) (invalidating a tax classification based on sex) and [Naber v. American Samoa](http://www.asbar.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=644) (invalidating one based on citizenship). The latter case basically ruled that citizenship-based taxation is unconstitutional, at least as applied by a territorial government, but the argument can be equally applied to the federal government.

Specifically, citizenship-based taxation is an irrational classification because the government's alleged reason for it is the "benefits of citizenship", which besides not requiring any funding from taxes, are actually benefits of nationality, and nonresident nationals without citizenship also receive the same benefits without being taxed. Therefore, imposing a tax only on a nonresident citizen in the exact same circumstances, solely due to a legally defined status, would be unconstitutional.

For more details, please see [this article](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2895609).

Comment: Citation to your own unpublished article is not an appropriate reference.

Comment: It wasn't supposed to be a reference, just a link for a longer explanation than what I could write here. The article itself has references. I also linked two court cases.

Answer (score -3):

- It is unconstitutional in that CBT is based solely on ownership of the
  individual by the state. Samuel Adams called this tributary slavery,
  and slavery is unconstitutional.
- Expatriates receive zero services for their tax dollars. Military
  services are between nations and not provided to individuals.
  Individuals must pay directly for rescue.
- The right to vote is not dependent on paying taxes but a right of
  citizenship. An example is Green Card holders who pay taxes but cannot
  vote.
- The right to return to the homeland also does not depend on taxes.
  Again, Green Card holders do not gain a right of passage simply by
  paying taxes.
- The U.S. government has condemned Eritrea for taxing its diaspora.

Comment: Even if you were right, you would not be right for these reasons. Policy reasons do not make a law unconstitutional. And the 13th Amendment is never a legal defense to tax laws of any kind as is well established. This is a frivolous argument that would have serious negative legal consequences for anyone who advanced it. I have recommended it for deletion.

Comment: So it is illegal to treat people as slaves but not when it involves taxing them?

Comment: The 13th Amendment has never stood because those people received services for their taxes. Cases have used it as an argument against socialism/communism.

In an expatriate's case, there are no services being provided. Any such services received such as the Aircraft Carrier Argument are services provided to nations, not individuals. Services to extract citizens from danger are paid for directly by those citizens.

The rights to return home and to vote are not services; they are rights. 

The only reason used to tax citizens living abroad is ownership of a citizen by the state.

Comment: As context, this policy was instituted in 1862/1863 to prevent Confederate sympathizers from not paying their fair share of taxes by fleeing to Canada. It made sense at the time. It also makes sense today to protect capital accumulated in the USA. When a person leaves, they should be taxed to account for future earnings of their capital. With limits, similar to estate taxes. But continued taxation of people adds undue burden on these people and on the administration of taxes.

Answer (score -3):

Parts of Citizenship Based Taxation are claimed Unconstitutional.

Republicans overseas has a lawsuit that FBAR and FATCA are unconstitutional on 8 claims.   Excessive Fines, Equal Protection, Right to Privacy, Right to protection against Unreasonable Search & Seizure.

A justification of taxation is not just representation, it also includes provision of local services (such as for resident U.S. persons including infrastructure, food stamps, unemployment, etc.), protection of local property, and protection of local rights.  The U.S. provides none of these to the 9 million U.S. Persons living overseas.

Comment: Do yo have any references to this lawsuit or to its resolution?

Answer (score -3):

Insofar as CBT (as enforced by FATCA) forces foreign banks to discriminate against expats by forcing them to sign agreements waiving their own privacy rights under local law or even close their accounts as a means of self protection, these laws force foreign institutions to violate the constitutional rights of US persons living abroad to maintain normal financial welfare as surrogates of the USG.

Comment: This forum is a place to state that law as it is, not as you argue that it should be without any legal authority to support it.